# Writing a Hashable instance for a large sum type

Tags: haskell, types, generic-programming

I have a large sum type

```
data Value
= VNull
| VDouble !Double
| VSci !Scientific
| VInt !Int
| VText !Text
| VTexts ![Text]
| VByteString !BS.ByteString
| VUTCTime !UTCTime
-- This goes on for quite a few more lines
```

I need a Hashable instance for this datatype. I could of course just type the instance by hand, but fortunately there is a default implementation for hashWithSalt based on generics.

Unfortunately - as far as I understand - this requires any type that can be "packed" inside the Value type to have a Hashable instance. Well, UTCTime does not have one.

So it looks like I can choose between two "suboptimal" solutions:

1. Type the Hashable instance by hand.
2. Write an orphan instance of Hashable UTCTime

I think there *should* be a third, "optimal" way: to only write an implementation for value constructors where there are not possible to do it automatically, i.e do something like this:

```
instance Hashable Value where
    hashWithSalt (VUTCTime t) = ... -- custom implementation
    hashWithSalt _ = ... -- use the default implementation
```

The question of course could be asked more generally: how can I re-use existing instance implementation in case of certain value constructors while having my own implementation in specific cases *without having to write boilerplate for each of the value constructors*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this particular situation, you should just use the [hashable-time package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashable-time-0.2.0.1/docs/Data-Hashable-Time.html), which defines the orphan instance in a standardised place.

In general for this kind of situation, I would either:

- Wrap the problematic type in a `newtype`, so you can define the instance locally without risking orphan-instance trouble.
- Just write the orphan instance. If it's unlikely that somebody else will provide a conflicting instance (i.e. when both class and type belong to obscure packages that are unlikely to be used in conjuction by anybody else), then this isn't something one really needs to worry about (even if duplicate-instance errors will happen at some point, this is very easy to fix and that'll actually be a good thing, removing the redundancy that a `newtype` would give).
- Add the instance to the library where it originally came from. If *either* the class or type come from a very common library, then it would probably make sense to define the instance in the less-common library. If that's open source, add the instance there and send the author a pull request.

Comment: Well, this is the most practical advice i.e. the one I'm actually going to use so I'm going to accept this one. Hashable-time does the dirty work for me regarding orphan instances :) Honestly I _could_ make an orphan instance for UTCTime since I'm writing an application for a particular problem, and it's highly unlikely anyone's going to use that code for anything else. The newtype solution is also viable, but requires some refactoring (patterns, prisms). Separating orphan instances into standalone packages seems like a good general strategy in such cases too. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer to add an orphan instance. Anyway, you can avoid that as follows.

Define this auxiliary type

```
data ValueNotTime
= VNull
| VDouble !Double
| VSci !Scientific
| VInt !Int
| VText !Text
| VTexts ![Text]
| VByteString !BS.ByteString
```

and derive Hashable automatically. Then, write an isomorphism

```
iso :: Value -> Either ValueNotTime UTCTime
osi :: Either ValueNotTime UTCTime -> Value
```

in the obvious way. Then,

```
instance Hashable Value where
    hashWithSalt v = case iso v of
       Left valueNoTime -> use derived implementation (hashWithSalt valueNoTime)
       Right utcTime    -> use custom implementation
```

Comment: This solution would make me to rewrite code that matches patterns on my Value and uses lenses/prisms, and that is about half the lines of code in the main application. Nice trick by the way, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good place to get the orphan instance from: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashable-time

---

If a generic implementation, say `genericHashWithSalt`, were exported (but it's currently not https://github.com/tibbe/hashable/issues/148) it would be possible to do

```
data Value_ utctime
  = ...
  | VUTCTime utctime
  deriving (Generic, Functor)
type Value = Value_ UtcTime

instance Hashable Value where
  hashWithSalt s (VUTCTime t) = (my custom implementation) s t
  hashWithSalt s v = genericHashWithSalt s (fmap (\_ -> ()) v)
```

And if you don't want to mangle your types, it should also be possible to modify the generic representation of `Value` as another way to hide `VUTCTime` before calling `genericHashWithSalt`.

```
 data Value = ...  -- the original one

 instance Hashable Value where
   hashWithSalt s (VUTCTime t) = (my custom implementation) s t
   hashWithSalt s t = genericHashWithSalt s (genericHideLastConstructor t)
   -- something like that...
```

Comment: Good one, thanks! I just made a pull request for that issue :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a type with a "hole", and fill in the hole in `hashWithSalt`. So:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}
import Data.Hashable
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Time
import GHC.Generics
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
data ValueF a
    = VNull
    | VDouble !Double
    | VInt !Int
    | VText !Text
    | VTexts ![Text]
    | VByteString !BS.ByteString
    | VUTCTime !a
    deriving (Hashable, Functor, Generic)

newtype Value = Value (ValueF UTCTime)

instance Hashable Value where
    hashWithSalt s (Value (VUTCTime t)) = {- whatever you're going to do here -}
    hashWithSalt s (Value v) = hashWithSalt s (() <$ v)
    -- OR
    -- hashWithSalt s (Value v) = hashWithSalt s (unsafeCoerce v :: Value ())
```

Comment: That's an interesting trick, thank you. :) Unfortunately this would require to do even more refactor than just writing hashWithSalt cases for all my Value constructors.